# How to install a bookworm package from a bullseye docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian, debian-based, bullseye

I'm currently building images from `python:3.9-slim-bullseye`.
I also need the latest version of [libleptonica-dev](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libleptonica-dev) which is only available for  `bookworm` and `sid`.

Currently, if I run `apt-get install -y libleptonica-dev` in my Dockerfile, it's installing the 1.79, but I need the 1.82.

Is there a way to install a package from a future debian version even if `bullseye-backport` doesn't exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN order to install libleptonica-dev version 1.82 from bookworm in Debian bullseye open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
wget -c http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/leptonlib/libleptonica-dev_1.82.0-3+b2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libleptonica-dev_1.82.0-3+b2_amd64.deb
```

If the link is broken when running wget, you can see the actual version links [here](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/amd64/libleptonica-dev/download).

Comment: If the link is broken when running `wget`, you can see the actual version links [here](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/amd64/libleptonica-dev/download)